# MySQL Binlog_Purge and Binlog_Executed

Tags: mysql, database-administration

Can someone help me understand these variables.

So I have a MySQL Group Replication setup, and then one of the nodes purged the binlog due to binlog_expiration..
so the other nodes recorded a warning, containing that they cannot replicate to server.

here

[Warning] [MY-011809] [Repl] Cannot replicate to server with server_uuid='aaaaa-a-aaaa-aaa' because the present server has purged required binary logs. The connecting server needs to replicate the missing transactions from elsewhere, or be replaced by a new server created from a more recent backup. To prevent this error in the future, consider increasing the binary log expiration period on the present server. The missing transactions are 'fffff-ff-ff'

What could be the impact of this?
Did the other nodes still replicate the missing transactions?

Comment: could you please share output of **show variables like '%expir%';**

Comment: I already adjusted the variables.. i just want to know what could be the impact of automatically purging binlogs in a group replication setup.. thank you..

Comment: Keep binary logs expiry as per RTO or RPO acceptance in your environment.

Comment: what do you mean? how?